Can't boot into linux partition after fresh installation of windows on my hard drive
The output of my fdisk -l looks like this
Disk /dev/sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: ST1000LX015-1U71
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D63C256E-EBAB-495B-B13F-E49980108B99
Device Start End Sectors Size Type
/dev/sda1 2048 206847 204800 100M EFI System
/dev/sda2 206848 239615 32768 16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3 239616 1951948799 1951709184 930.6G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4 1951948800 1953521663 1572864 768M Windows recovery environment
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: CT500P3PSSD8
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 6262E89B-3B26-4009-AE7D-8FB5BDDED59F
Device Start End Sectors Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1 34 32767 32734 16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p2 32768 976771071 976738304 465.7G Linux filesystem

As you can see, I have 2 drives, a hard drive with Windows installed, and an SSD with Linux installed. I deleted all partitions on my hard drive to do a clean install of Windows, but the boot manager for Linux also got wiped with it I think. So it doesn't show grub. But it wouldn't even show up in the bios boot menu.
Here's what I have tried so far:
Created a live USB of Linux Mint. Mounted the 2nd partition on my SSD, the one with the Linux filesystem. Mounted /dev, /proc and /sys. chrooted into /mnt. I then ran grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id=GRUB, but it returned these warnings:
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: warning: EFI variables cannot be set on this system.
grub-install: warning: You will have to complete the GRUB setup manually.

Installation finished. No error reported.

I don't have an EFI partition on my SSD by the way.I thought mounting the EFI partition on my hard drive might help, but it didn't.
Then I gave up on grub, and tried installing refind. I ran the refind-install command but it said that EFI variables are not supported on this system.
Please help me fix this. If you need any more context, I will be here. Thank you for your help. I really need to boot into this Linux partition soon.
It is solved! I used this tool:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
It seems like a pretty nifty tool for all boot related issues

Microsoft Windows wasn't designed to coexist with other operating systems. If dual boot is needed, Windows must be installed first (keeping part of the hard disk reserved for other OS), then the other OS.

If your fstab has the mount of the old ESP, that is why install fails. I prefer to have an ESP on every drive, especially every drive with an install. Boot-Repair's advanced mode lets you choose an install & a drive (with in ESP), so that is why Boot-Repair usually works.

Please post your solution as an answer so the question can be marked as solved. Ideally, tell us how you used boot repair.

grub-install: warning: EFI variables cannot be set on this system.
grub-install: warning: You will have to complete the GRUB setup manually.

This probably means you booted the live-Mint in legacy BIOS mode. You should boot it in UEFI mode instead, so that you will keep access to UEFI runtime services, which is a pre-requisite to setting (U)EFI variables.
You can confirm this by checking for the existence of the /sys/firmware/efi/ directory: if the directory exists, the UEFI runtime services are available.

I don't think it's sufficient to mount just the partitions you mounted in your chroot environment. Try these (source):
sudo -s  # get a root shell
mount /dev/sdXY /mnt
mount /dev/sdXX /mnt/boot/efi
for m in /proc /run /dev{,/pts} /sys{,/firmware/efi/efivars}; do \
  mount --bind $m /mnt$m; done
chroot /mnt

# now, in the chroot environment
grub-install /dev/sdX  # or grub-install /dev/sdXX
grub-install --recheck /dev/sdX
update-grub

In my case, I kept trying to do this from memory (bad idea), and

I didn't realize that /sys/firmware/efi/efivars was itself a separate mount

so bind-mounting /sys alone didn't propagate that into the chroot environment
so you would keep getting that "EFI variables cannot be set on this system" error message in the chroot, even though you were clearly booted in EFI mode from your bootable USB stick or whatever


I forgot that update-grub was required to actually populate the boot menu with other detected operating systems

I should add that these steps alone didn't help me get my system bootable (still working on that), but I was finally able to understand and prevent the "EFI variables cannot be set on this system" error message.
